# Win 7 API to set Power key to Sleep rather than Shutdown

Tags: windows-7

Every time I boot my Win 7 system, the power keys are set to shut the system down.  Every time, I reset the keys so that they cause the system to sleep. But sometimes I forget, and then programs are closed harshly.

I want to write a program that will force the power keys to cause the system to sleep rather than power down.  Then I can run that program each time I boot, and I will avoid the problem.

Does anyone know the API calls to tell Win 7 that the power key should mean "sleep"?

Comment: First of all, why was a programming question moved away from a programming site? Secondly, can anyone answer the actual question I asked? How do I write a program to set this OS parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually I don't think you need to make a program for this.
I'm using a laptop, but its the same Windows 7.
Go to the Control Panel, look for `Power Options`. then, choose you'r preferred power option, click `Change plan settings` and set whatever you want.
Next time you reboot, as long as you stay on that plan, the setting (e.g power button putting computer to sleep) should stay.

Comment: Thank you, but every time I do this, something changes it afterward.  I need a way to override whatever is overriding my choices.

Comment: I think it's a windows-related problem, as long as you click save, it should stay that way. Contact Microsoft or something.

Comment: Keep in mind, if you have pending updates, it will override the default wit shutdown.